# How can I create a linux command that gets the value of a variable from a text file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
serverPass i_am_a_password
```

I am basically looking for a command so I can set an environment variable to `i_am_a_password`.

I've tried using grep with `serverPass` but I am not sure how to split the output and somehow pipe it to a environment variable assignment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a server configuration file where other lines are allowed to have other directives? Or is it a file where any and all lines look as described?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
PASSWORD=$(cut -d' ' -f2 password.txt)
```

Now you will have the password in the environment variable called PASSWORD.
Test it with `echo $PASSWORD`

`-d` is the delimiter and `-f2` means the field to output.

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is an option, you can try

```
$ var=$(sed 's/[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/' input_file)
$ echo "$var"
i_am_a_password
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# if file.txt contains only password line
serverPass=$(awk '{print $2}' file.txt)
echo $serverPass
i_am_a_password

# otherwise use pattern
serverPass=$(awk '/^serverPass / {print $2}' file.txt) 
echo $serverPass
i_am_a_password

# or source all variables from file.txt after changing blank to "="
source <(cat file.txt | tr ' ' '=')
echo $serverPass
i_am_a_password
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that 1-line input file you show, all you need to do is read the line:

```
read -r _ var < file
```

Look:

```
$ cat file
serverPass i_am_a_password

$ read -r _ var < file

$ echo "$var"
i_am_a_password
```